# How to filter specific vector using matching condition in R

Tags: r

I have two sets of Input vector. Either Policy Number or Contract Number comes as value for these inputs. But at a time only one will come.

I need to extract either of these Number and fit into policy_nr variable.  The code works fine If I explicitly extract.

If I am trying to put OR operator and  I am getting this Error

invalid 'x' type in 'x || y'

**My Input Type 1**

```
kk
 [1] "DUPLICATE x"                                                                                                                
 [2] "ifa’-"                                                                                                                      
 [3] "UPLICAT EXIDE Life"                                                                                                         
 [4] "Insurance"                                                                                                                  
 [5] "02-01-2020"                                                                                                                 
 [6] "Mr DEV WHITE T"                                                                                                       
 [7] "Contract Number : 123456"
```

**My Input Type 2**

```
kk
 [1] "DUPLICATE x"                                                                                                                
 [2] "ifa’-"                                                                                                                      
 [3] "UPLICAT EXIDE Life"                                                                                                         
 [4] "Insurance"                                                                                                                  
 [5] "02-01-2020"                                                                                                                 
 [6] "Mr CRAIG WHITE T"                                                                                                       
 [7] "Policy Number : 7890"
```

Code

```
policy_nr <- str_trim(sub(".*:", "", kk[grepl("Contract Number",kk)] ), side = c("both"))  || str_trim(sub(".*:", "", kk[grepl("Policy Number",kk)] ), side = c("both"))
```

Answer (score 2):

Just concatenate the character vector into one using `paste`, because the number might be at any element. You can encode the OR operator in a regular expression like this: `"(Policy|Contract)"`

```r
library(tidyverse)

record1 <- c(
  "DUPLICATE x",
  "ifa’-",
  "UPLICAT EXIDE Life",
  "Insurance",
  "02-01-2020",
  "Mr DEV WHITE T",
  "Contract Number : 123456"
)

record2 <- c(
  "DUPLICATE x",
  "ifa’-",
  "UPLICAT EXIDE Life",
  "Insurance",
  "02-01-2020",
  "Mr CRAIG WHITE T",
  "Policy Number : 7890"
)

extract_number <- function(x) {
  x %>%
    paste0(collapse = " ") %>%
    str_extract("(Policy|Contract) Number : [0-9]+") %>%
    str_extract("[0-9]+") %>%
    as.numeric()
}


extract_number(record1)
#> [1] 123456
extract_number(record2)
#> [1] 7890
```

<sup>Created on 2021-12-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

You can use this pattern: `'(?<=(Policy|Contract) Number : ).\\d+'` to extract numbers after `Policy Number` or `Contract Number`

```
library(tidyverse)

kk1 <- c(
  "DUPLICATE x",
  "ifa’-",
  "UPLICAT EXIDE Life",
  "Insurance",
  "02-01-2020",
  "Mr DEV WHITE T",
  "Contract Number : 123456"
)

kk2 <- c(
  "DUPLICATE x",
  "ifa’-",
  "UPLICAT EXIDE Life",
  "Insurance",
  "02-01-2020",
  "Mr CRAIG WHITE T",
  "Policy Number : 7890"
)

kk1 %>% paste(collapse = ' ') %>% 
    str_extract_all('(?<=(Policy|Contract) Number : ).\\d+')

kk2 %>% paste(collapse = ' ') %>% 
    str_extract_all('(?<=(Policy|Contract) Number : ).\\d+')
```

[image]

Comment: Why does this positive look behind (`?<=`) work? The argument `pattern` of function `str_extract_all` clearly requires POSIX regexes. However, PCRE extensions are not part of that standard.

Comment: It does work.  And my R version is 4.1.1 and stringr version 1.4.0. You can try it.

Comment: My question was why and not does. `stringr` uses `stringi` which uses `ICU` as the regex engine. Like PCRE, ICU supports look arrounds, but not recursions. So it indeed works.